# JavaScript prototype password generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, passwords, generator, prototype-programming

I wrote a simple JS script to generate a random password.

### My code that work now but with just small letters

```
function Password(l) {
    this.l = l;
}

Password.prototype.generate = function () {
    var p = "";

for (let i=0; i < this.l; i++) {
    p = p + String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97 + 1) + 97));
}
return p;
};

p = new Password(8);
console.log(p.generate());
```

For finding a char code

```
 console.log("A".charCodeAt(0));
 console.log("Z".charCodeAt(0));
 console.log("0".charCodeAt(0));
 console.log("9".charCodeAt(0));
```

One of my idea for get this done but I don't know how ?

```
if (Math.random() < .5) {
     console.log("OK");
} else {
    console.log("NOT OK");
}
console.log(Math.random());
```

Thanks in advance for this
And if some of write code it's better to understand

Update 1 : Someone complete the code with new features means Capital letters and add numbers to it with shuffle.

Comment: What do you want us to help you do? Rewrite this code to be more readable/faster or add new functionality?

Comment: I'm am not entirely sure what you are asking but this is from "MDN Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web Crypto API instead, and more precisely the window.crypto.getRandomValues() method." courtesy of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) I am not sure how using a random number generator would have anything to do with logging to the console the unicode number for a character at index 0 of a string. Please be clear on what you are asking.

Comment: at first. Thanks to all, Matthew advise is cool, the answer for Boris is yes thanks to you , I want generate a password with A-Z and a-z And 1-9 just these , for a-z small I write a code but don't know how can I add 2 others features to it, also I show to you the advise sample algorithm for that with if condition.  Thanks to whom write a code in that way and generate random pass, if you run that code means in html and open html and open console log of browser you will see generated pass with only small letters but I want add numbers and capital letters too in the way of that algorithm I wrote.